# Electron: How to load webview inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am unable to load webview inside iframe. When i add webview tag it is not visible on preview, but it exists as tag . Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

[image: picture]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow stefan! please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. it would be best to post codes instead of screenshots. also, please provide [mcve] to help in debugging the issue. have you enabled the `webview` in the `BrowserWindow` parameters?

Comment: Thanks, Tesa. Yes, i allowed webview with attribute webviewTag when creating Browser Window and it works if i put it in main window. But if i put webview tag inside iframe, as i showed on picture, it is not visible.

Comment: hang on a sec.. `webview` inside an `iframe`? have you tried to put `webview` outside the `iframe`? thing is `webview` is electron specific and i believe `iframe` only allows html elements not electron's. try use `webview` on your `iframe` and use `file://` for referencing the file.

Comment: The reason why i am doing this is that Google has decided to kill Chrome apps and i want to migrate that app to electron. I find Electron as the best framework for it. In that app user can open more than 1 tab and inside each tab run site. :/ Using iframe i can easily communicate with each tab and if i want send something to webview, which is inside tab, i use inject script.